# CSS property min-height causing margin issue?

Tags: html, css, spacing

I am trying to make a div which has a CSS-generated triangle attached to the bottom of it. It works perfectly when the height of the div above is set using the CSS `height` property, but when I use `min-height` instead, it results in there being an unwanted gap, which I am unable to get rid of using the `margin` CSS properties.

Does anyone have any idea how I could get rid of the issue?

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 17px 10.5px 0 10.5px;
}

.divider1 {
  min-height: 80px;
}

.divider2 {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider1" style="background-color: blue">
  <h1>This one doesn't work</h1>
</div>
<div class="triangle" style="border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent"></div>

<div class="divider2" style="background-color: green">
  <h1>But this one does?</h1>
</div>
<div class="triangle" style="border-color: green transparent transparent transparent"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `h1` element's `margin` is collapsing in the second example. This is known as [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). To resolve this, one option would be to simply remove the `h1` element's `margin` in the first example.

For what it's worth, the following applies:

> [**Box Model - 8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> The bottom margin of an in-flow block box with a `height` of `auto` and a `min-height` of zero collapses with its last in-flow block-level child's bottom margin if the box has no bottom padding and no bottom border and the child's bottom margin does not collapse with a top margin that has clearance.
>
> A box's own margins collapse if the `min-height` property is zero, and it has neither top or bottom borders nor top or bottom padding, and it has a `height` of either `0` or `auto`, and it does not contain a line box, and all of its in-flow children's margins (if any) collapse.

As a side note, I'd suggest adding the triangle via a pseudo-element that is absolutely positioned *relative* to the parent element with a `top` value of `100%`.

In doing so, it will work regardless of whether the parent has a `height`/`min-height`, and regardless of the element's `margin`.

```css
.triangle-after {
  position: relative;
}
.triangle-after:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0; height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 17px 10.5px 0 10.5px;
}

.divider1 {
  min-height: 80px;
}
.divider1.triangle-after:after {
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
.divider2 {
  height: 80px;
}
.divider2.triangle-after:after {
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider1 triangle-after" style="background-color: blue">
  <h1>Both of these work now.</h1>
</div>

<div class="divider2 triangle-after" style="background-color: green">
  <h1>Both of these work now.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of margin collapsing. This should fix it:

```
h1 {margin-top:0;}
```

Margin collapsing occurs in three basic cases:

> Adjacent siblings:
>
> The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed
>   (except when the later sibling needs to be cleared past floats). For
>   example:
>
> ```
> <p>The bottom margin of this paragraph is collapsed...</p>
>  <p>...with the top margin of this paragraph.</p>
> ```
>
> Parent and first/last child::
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline
>   content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the
>   margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline
>   content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the
>   margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child,
>   then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the
>   parent. :
>
> Empty blocks:
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content,
>   height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its
>   margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse.

More on [developer.mozilla.com](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

```css
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17px 10.5px 0 10.5px;
}
.divider1 {
    min-height: 80px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
.divider2 {
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider1" style="background-color: blue">
     <h1>This one works now!</h1>

</div>
<div class="triangle" style="border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent"></div>
<div class="divider2" style="background-color: green">
     <h1>But this one does?</h1>

</div>
<div class="triangle" style="border-color: green transparent transparent transparent"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much; this (`margin: 0`) does indeed fix it! Could you explain why this is the case, because using the Inspect Element in Chrome didn't seem to show the margin extending that far?

Comment: You're welcome! This is because of [margin collapsing](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/)

Comment: Basically you can avoid such unexpected results by using a CSS Reset.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the problem is with the `h1` tag. If you were to remove the margin on the `h1` it would work. You could also add padding to the `.divider1` for it to work properly. Padding will be your better option since it accounts for any other elements having margin.